# XY Co-ordinate information for Start and end point of Line in vector layer

Tags: qgis, coordinates, fields-attributes, vector-layer, xy

How can we get XY coordinate for Start and end point of Line in vector layer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the field calculator for this task. see screenshot below. The expressions for getting the coordinates for the start- and endpoint are:

```
x(start_point( $geometry)) --x startpoint
y(start_point( $geometry)) --y startpoint
x(end_point( $geometry)) --x endpoint
y(end_point( $geometry)) --y endpoint
```

If you want to have the point just use

```
start_point( $geometry)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add these coordinates to the attribute table of the line vector layer.

1. Open the attribute table of the line vector layer
2. Select Open field calculator icon
3. Create a column for the x coordinate of the start point (if you check virtual field it will be recalculated if you reopen the attribute table, otherwise you have to update manually the fields after editing the layer geometry)
   [image]
4. Similar way you can add new field for the y coordinate of start point: `$y_at(0)`, for the end point use -1 parameter for `$x_at` and `$y_at` (e.g. `$x_at(-1)`)
   [image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but I am getting a different Co-ordinate value while using the above geometry formula than shown in the firstX ,firstY & lastX ,lastY under Derived.

Comment: How do you ask the coordinates? With identify tool you get three different coordinates and sometime none of them is the coordinate of the start and end point. To check the stored coordinates make the layer editable and use the vertex tool and right click on the feature to get the list of coordinates. You can see the stored coordinates this way.

Answer (score 1):

with pyqgis,

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name_here')[0]
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    my_vertices = f.geometry().vertices()
    vertices = [v for v in my_vertices]

startPoint = vertices[0]
endPoint = vertices[-1]
```